# ASP.NET Webforms Project created with VS2012 RC does not run in VS2012 RTM

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I used the RC version of Visual Studio 2012 to create an ASP.NET Webforms project and I intentionally took the 4.0 version of .Net and of the project template to avoid complications after the release of VS2012.

Now I anyway bumped into the problem, that is revealed in the following error message:

```
'jquery' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.
```

As I noticed in the references, following assembly references are broken:

- Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery
- Microsoft.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Component
- System.Web.Providers

I tried to re-install jQuery using NuGet but did not find these assemblies.
If I now create a new .Net 4.0 ASP.NET Webforms project in Visual Studio 2012 I get a lot of new references which are not present in my current (originally created in the RC-version, now opened in VS2012 RTM), like:

- AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery
- AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined

but I can't find them among reference sources if I try to add a new reference to my original project.

How can I make my application runnable in VS2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check packages

```
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.1.7.1
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.20
```

make sure the following dlls are in the lib folder

```
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined.dll
```

And check the reference in your project to make sure all references are resolved.

Sometimes, the dlls didn't added to the source control and when you do a get latest from the source control these two dlls are missing.