# 'jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

I know this has been asked a hundred times before, but alas, no solutions here work for this NuGet bug in VS2012. All I did was upgrade to the latest Ajax toolkit and my site is broken as a result.

I've tried uninstalling the NuGet package and reinstalling everything with no joy.

I have jQuery, jQueryUI, and the site builds just fine, however, at runtime, it crashes with this dreaded error. adding .js to the end creates more errors, and so forth.

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tksm1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
        <Scripts>            
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/search.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

All references are pointing correctly as far as I can tell. I've "cleaned" the solution, deleted bin folder, etc, etc. no joy there either. I've copied and pasted other solutions, again no joy.

Version: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.5.51641
Windows 8.1 (updated as of today).

Should I reinstall VS?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12662501 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974767/jquery-is-not-a-valid-script-name-the-name-must-end-in-js

Comment: That only works for the old version of jQuery, update it in NuGet and you'll get the new reference error. Deleting the old references and replacing them creates more errors. I restored back to the old version of jQuery and jQueryUI and I have it working. It looks like there is no way to upgrade via NuGet - a bug of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I figured out the most painless way of doing this.
I restored a backup (good idea to make backups) of the site in question.
Before loading it into VS2012, I deleted the \packages\ folder completely.
Then, I opened the project and VS restored the \packages\ folder and all references (by dumb luck, I discovered that VS will rebuild things for you).
I still had the old versions of jQuery, jQUI, ACTK, etc. and tested to make sure everything worked.
The solution this time around is to avoid the NuGet GUI altogether (there is some sort of bug whereby it will not uninstall things properly).
I went to the command line instead and typed in the appropriate commands to install the latest versions (the old versions were removed properly this time).
I cleaned & rebuilt the solution and it works just fine now. (no editing of .config files required).